# What are the benefits of caching instances of a class?

Tags: php, oop, caching, apc

I have an application in which I repeatedly use the same (big) class. Since I use AJAX for that App, I always have to create a new object of this class. Someone advised me to cache an instance of this class and use it whenever it is required (using apc in a php environment)

What are the benefits of it ? is it really saving some time ?

```
    $this->tickets_persist = unserialize(@apc_fetch("Tickets"));

    if (!$this->tickets_persist) {
            $this->tickets_persist = new Tickets_Persistance(); // Take long time
            apc_store("Tickets", serialize($this->tickets_persist));
    }
```

Comment: If it is quicker to cache it, then do so; there's no value in doing it if creating an instance is extremely quick. An example of where you might cache object instances is in an ORM, since each row object (or resultset object) requires slow database queries to recreate from scratch.

Comment: What is a "big" class? Lots of code? Lots of data? Lots of computation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefits are only really realized if you are dealing with a class that has an expensive instantiation cost. If there is things that take a lot of time, memory or other resource being done in the constructor of the class (for example: reading an XML sitemap and building a complex data structure to build your navigation.) you can dodge this by leveraging caching.

It's also worth noting that resources (like database links and such) are not able to be cached and they would have to be re-established after the object is unserialized (here is where the `__sleep` and `__wakeup` magic method comes in).

Answer (score 4):

It would only be worth it if your object requires a lot of processing during instantiation. Caching will not help you with "big" objects, it will help you when you want to avoid processing that can be repeated. In your case, it would only be worth it if your construct method required a lot of processing. Let's take an example of how caching would work in the context of a webpage :

1. On first page load, instantiate and cache the object for x hours
2. On any subsequent page load for the next x hours, it will directly return the object, without processing the instantiation
3. After x hours, the cached object will be expired, the next page load will re instantiate the object and re cache it

Your application will behave in the same way, the only difference is that you will "re-use" the instantiation process that has already been done.